# Clear values in a linked combobox each time when selecting value in first combo using access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two comboboxes they are sync each other. After selecting first combobox value and then corresponding values will display in 2nd combobox . Each time when i select first combo box then previously reselected 2nd combo value should be clear.
I'm using below code in the **OnChange** event of first combo1.But it is not working.

```
             Private Sub combo1_Change()
             Me.combo2.RowSource = ""
             End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
      Private Sub combo1_Change()
      Me.combo2.Value = ""
      End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
Call combo2.Clear
```

Or this

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To ComboBox2.ListCount
    ComboBox2.RemoveItem (0)
Next i
```

Comment: **.Clear** Method not available

Comment: Maybe its not showing in the intellisence but its defiantly there. I've also brought another method you could use